Ejecutar Hilos en c++ pero asincronos
quisiera pedir su ayuda. Intento hacer en C++ que se ejecuten 2 hilos que no estén no sincronizados, los cuales utilizaban las funciones de Windows.h para presionar cada uno una tecla diferente a diferentes intervalos. Solo puedo lograr que ambas teclas salgan al mismo tiempo(z y 8):

estos son los encabezados:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h> // FUNCIONES PARA EL CURSOR
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

y estas las funciones:
void keyPress(WORD keyCode, INPUT input,int tiempo)
{

    input.ki.wVk = keyCode;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input)); // Press key?

    // Sleep(500); // ideal para soltar luego
    Sleep(tiempo);
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input)); // Release key?q
    // cout << "Gracias. Que tengua buen dia" << endl;
}

void cuenta_regresiva()
{
    
    cout << "Espere 3" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "Espere 2" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "Espere 1" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
}

void tecla1(INPUT input,int tiempo)
{
    //Sleep(300);
    keyPress(0x5A, input,tiempo); // tecla z
}

void tecla2(INPUT input,int tiempo)
{
    //Sleep(1000);
    keyPress(0x38, input,tiempo); // numero 8
}

int main()
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    cuenta_regresiva();

    while (true)
    {
        if (GetKeyState('X'))
        {
            break;
        }
        std::thread t1(tecla1, (input),200);
        std::thread t2(tecla2, (input),300);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

    }

    return 0;
}

Podrían indicarme cómo podría hacer que se presionen en tiempos diferentes.

No estoy en windows, así que no puedo probar bien el código. Sin embargo, para que el código funcione, las funciones tecla1() y tecla2() que ejecutan los threads deben mantenerse funcionando con un while, y no retornar hasta que se quiera que el código finalice.
El enfoque para solucionar el problema debería ser este:
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> salir = false;

void keyPress(WORD keyCode, INPUT input,int tiempo)
{

    input.ki.wVk = keyCode;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input)); // Press key?

    // Sleep(500); // ideal para soltar luego
    Sleep(tiempo);
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input)); // Release key?q
    // cout << "Gracias. Que tengua buen dia" << endl;
}

void cuenta_regresiva()
{
    
    cout << "Espere 3" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "Espere 2" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "Espere 1" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
}

void tecla1(INPUT input,int tiempo)
{
    while (true)
    {
      if (GetKeyState('X'))
          salir = true

      Sleep(300);
      keyPress(0x5A, input,tiempo); // tecla z

      if (salir)
          return;
    }
}

void tecla2(INPUT input,int tiempo)
{
    while (true)
    {
      if (GetKeyState('X'))
          salir = true

      Sleep(1000);
      keyPress(0x38, input,tiempo); // numero 8

      if (salir)
          return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

    cuenta_regresiva();

    std::thread t1(tecla1, (input),200);
    std::thread t2(tecla2, (input),300);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}


Claro. Su código falla porque cada ciclo crea 2 hilos nuevos. Lo que sí: puede dejar el if (GetKeyState('X')) en la función main para no repetir código y poner como condición del while, !salir.

Tus hilos ya son asíncronos, es el sistema operativo el que decidirá en que orden se ejecutará cada hilo y con que prioridad, si se están ejecutando de manera (aparentemente) secuencial es porque así lo ha decidido el SO.
He hecho una versión de tu código en un compilador online y podemos ver que el resultado es diferente:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

bool sigue = true;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

template <char letra>
void escribe_letra()
{
    while (sigue)
    {
        if (std::ofstream o{"test.txt", std::ios_base::app})
            o << letra;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1{escribe_letra<'z'>};
    std::thread t2{escribe_letra<'8'>};

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    sigue = false;

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    if (std::ifstream i{"test.txt"})
    {
        std::string linea;
        std::getline(i, linea);
        std::cout << linea;
    }

    return 0;
}

En diferentes ejecuciones he obtenido:
8zz8z8z88z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8zz8z8z88z8zz8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z88z8zz88z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8zz88z8zz88zz88zz8z8z88z8z8zz88z8z8zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88z8zz8z88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz8z88z8z8z8zz8z8z8z8z88z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8zz8z88zz88z8z8z8z8z8z8z8zz8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z88z8zz8z88zz8z8


8z8z8zz88zz8z8z88z8z8z8zz8z88z8z8zz88z8zz8z88z8zz88zz8z8z88zz88z8z8z8zz8z8z88z8z8zz88z8z8zz8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z88z8z8zz8z88zz8z8z8z88z8zz88z8zz88z8zz8z8z8z88zz8z8z88zz88z8zz8z88zz8z88z8zz88zz8z8z8z8z88z8z8z8zz8z88z8z8z8zz88z8zz88zz8z8z88zz8z8z88z8z8z8z8z8zz8z88z8zz88z8zz88zz8z88z8zz8z8z88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88z8zz8z8z8z88z8z8zz88z8z8zz8z8z8z8z8z8z8z88z8z8z8zz88z8z8z8zz8z88zz8z8z8z8z88z8zz88zz8z88z


z88z8z8z8z8z8z8zz88zz88z8z8zz8z88z8zz8z88zz8z88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88zz88z8zz8z8z8z8z8z88zz8z88zz8z8z8z8z88zz88zz88z8zz88zz88zz88zz88z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z8z

Puedes ver el código funcionando en Compiler explorer.
